# Angular - Service to calculate sum of 2 scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Learning how to use services but really having a hard time. Trying to make a simple calculator to provide the sum of 2 scope value (2 inputs). My functions seems to be taking the values and sending them okay. But my result scope dosent seem to be changing or updating at all when I fire my functions.

Here what I got so far:

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/528/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
   Val1: <input ng-model="val1"> {{val1}} <br> 
   Val2: <input ng-model="val2"> {{val2}} <br><br>
   Total result: <input ng-model="result"> {{result}} <br>
   <input type="button" ng-click="calculate_controller()" value="Calculate"><br>
</body>
```

SCRIPT:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, businessRepository) {
       $scope.result = businessRepository.result_service();
       $scope.val1 = "";
       $scope.val2 = "";
       $scope.calculate_controller = function() { 
        console.log("Hello");
        businessRepository.calculate_service($scope.val1, $scope.val2) 
       };
})
  .factory('businessRepository', function($http) {
    return {
        result_service: function(data){
         console.log("test function launched", data)
         return data;
        },
        calculate_service: function(val1, val2){
          var result = val1 + val2;
          this.result_service(result); 
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `data` from the service `businessRepository` and need to consume it in the controller `myController`. Also you need to convert `val1` and `val2` to `Number`. Here in snippet I have used `+` to achieve it.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function ($scope, businessRepository) {
    $scope.calculate_controller = function () {
        $scope.result = businessRepository.calculate_service(+$scope.val1, +$scope.val2)
    };
})
.factory('businessRepository', function ($http) {
    return {
        result_service: function (data) {
            return data || 0;
        },
        calculate_service: function (val1, val2) {
            var result = val1 + val2;
            //Return the data from
            return this.result_service(result);
        }
    };
});
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, businessRepository) {
    $scope.calculate_controller = function() {
      $scope.result = businessRepository.calculate_service(+$scope.val1, +$scope.val2)
    };
  })
  .factory('businessRepository', function($http) {
    return {
      result_service: function(data) {
        return data;
      },
      calculate_service: function(val1, val2) {
        var result = val1 + val2;
        return this.result_service(result);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  Val1:
  <input ng-model="val1">
  <br>Val2:
  <input ng-model="val2">
  <br>
  <br>Total result:
  <input ng-model="result">{{result}}
  <br>
  <input type="button" ng-click="calculate_controller()" value="Calculate">
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting, been searching the web for a while. Never seen it done like this before. Seems to be working great in angular 1.6 as well. Awesome, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the calculate_service by :

```
calculate_service: function (val1, val2) {
    var result = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2);
    return this.result_service(result);
}
```

And  calculate_controller by :

```
$scope.calculate_controller = function () {
    $scope.result = businessRepository.calculate_service($scope.val1, $scope.val2)
};
```